# how to get value of another variable from database using foreign key laravel

Tags: laravel

my database is in sqlserver i already migrate my database with foreign key but the problem is how to get data of another Table using Foreing key
so im trying to edit a task & i have to get project Description from project table & i have foreing key betwen task table & project table but it dont work

````
             <option value="{{ $task->FKID_Projet}}" selected>    {{ $task->FKID_Projet->N_Projet->Proj_Description}}  </option>
                             </select>
</div>```
this is my database migration : 
```Schema::table('Tache', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->foreign(['FKID_User_Realisateur'], 'FK_Tache_SAD_USERS')->references(['ID_User'])->on('SAD_USERS')->onUpdate('NO ACTION')->onDelete('NO ACTION');
           $table->foreign(['FKID_Tache_Statut'], 'FK_Tache_Tache_Statut')->references(['N_Tache_Statut'])->on('Tache_Statut')->onUpdate('NO ACTION')->onDelete('NO ACTION');
           $table->foreign(['FKID_Projet'], 'FK_Tache_Projet')->references(['N_Projet'])->on('Projet')->onUpdate('NO ACTION')->onDelete('NO ACTION');```
````

Comment: Hi aymane, could you please add your data models and database migrations?

Comment: Yes please add models, we're quite curious to know if you've defined relationships

Answer (score 0):

Your question has ambiguity at all if you have model or not but I assume you have not.

~The pre-defined approach in Laravel is `eloquent model` , it is easy, rapid and formal way to retrieve, update and save date to database, for your case firstly define model for your tables and make relationships between them if you do not want to make model and relationship between the table then you need to join the value using query builder, there is bunch of instructions in Laravel's official docs for both of them (**eloquent and query builder**)